# How to lookup the function addresses of ALL functions instrumented with gcc -finstrument-functions flag?

Tags: gcc, instrumentation, dladdr

This option, as described in the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html), adds instrumentation calls at the entry and exit of functions.  These calls pass the start address of the function, which I then lookup with dladdr to determine the function name from the address that was passed.

My issue is that occasionally there is no match found when using `dladdr`.  That is case because `-finstrument-functions` will also add instrumentation before and after a call to a function when it doesn't have access to its source.  This is the case for example with a function library like `memset`.

How can I look up the address for those functions to retrieve their name when `dladdr` fails to find a match?  The doc says that all addresses "may be looked up exactly in the symbol table" but as far as I can tell the symbol table (using `-t` option of `objdmp`) doesn't provide lookup info for library functions.